# Is there any public documentation on Odoo v.17 or v.16 data model?

Tags: odoo

I'm looking for a source where I can find the data model and attributes for the core models, specifically for ER model and (even better) data dictionary with attributes and PK/FK's.

I looked everywhere within Odoo's resources and couldn't find it...

Comment: AFAIK there is none. Set up a Odoo, install all modules/apps and just use database tools for postgres to get it yourself.